# How to write a COM server in raw C?

Tags: c, com

I am studying COM. I think the best way to get a thorough understanding of COM is write one without any COM framework such as ATL. I have written a COM server in raw C++, and now I want to write one in plain raw C. How could I do this? Is there any tutorial?

Many thanks.

Comment: For the love of all things holy man, unless your job requires you to study COM, DO NOT GO DOWN THIS PATH. I've read Box's book, Rogerson's, and a handful of others. COM under C is pure misery. COM under C++ is half misery. COM itself is misery. Sure, a lot of our so-called "modern" .NET libraries *depend* on COM, but there's a very good reason why that stuff has been abstracted out of existence. Nobody touches COM anymore unless they have to. Please listen to Greg's advice below, and mine, and turn from this path of the Dark Side you've taken, and save yourself the joys of working with BSTRs.

Comment: Thanks guys. COM is a monster, I totally agree. But so is my boss. I have to somehow get the skeleton and essence of COM in less than 1 month... God bless me. If there's any short cut, please tell me. Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: For the purpose of satisfying your boss, the essence of COM is C++. "COM under C" is a skeleton only when you consider it's dead and buried for almost two decades now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don Box's book [Essential COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465) is one of the best that explains everything about COM from the ground up. Recommended.

COM, however, is decade old technology that's a heck of a lot of work to do in C, and Don Box (previously considered one of the experts) doesn't even touch it anymore. Take what you will from that.

Comment: -1 For first para (I think Box's books are (euphemistically) not very good. +1 For the second. For a real COM from the ground up, read Inside COM by Dale Rogerson.

Answer (score 4):

Writing COM servers in C is not impossible.  It is just that COM code is already beefy, it will be quite a bit beefier in C since you don't get help from the built-in v-table support that a compliant C++ compiler generates.  Or a class library like ATL.  You have to create your own.

A good source for COM example code written in C is the WINE project.  For example, the [implementation of the IGlobalInterfaceTable interface](http://wine.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.5/git_8c-source.html).  Note the GITClassFactoryVtbl in that code, that's the interface dispatch table for the class factory, and StdGlobalInterfaceTableImpl_Vtbl, the dispatch table for IGlobalInterfaceTable.

Not so sure that this will give you a deeper insight in COM programming.  It is unlikely you'll ever write a real server like this.  Have you written an out-of-process server yet?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does give me great insight. I have written an in-process com server in C++.

Comment: +1 for this answer provide some information on "COM under C",not just criticize the evil of COM